# How to trace the unsecured http requests from a secured webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to make a website secured after the user is logged into the website.But in the https pages i am getting some http requests.How we can trace them or remove from the code?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to enable extended logging on your IIS server and check the referrer header fields submitted by user-agents.